# Restore Tensorflow Variable files from Plaintext files

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I'm using this code to dump all variable files to plaintext:

```
for x in tf.all_variables():

    log("saved variable '{}'.".format(x.name))
    newname = x.name.replace("/",".") 
    current_file = os.path.join(var_outdir, newname)
    file = open(current_file, 'w')         
    x.eval(session = CONFIG.model.tf_manager.sessions[0]).tofile(file, sep='\t')
    file.close()
```

What is the best was to restore the model from these files?

Edit:

Save function:

```
def SaveToPlaintext(self, variable_files: Union[str, List[str]]) -> None:
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    var_outdir = os.path.join(cwd,'variables/')
#print(cwd, var_outdir)
    log("saving variable files to '{}'."
        .format(var_outdir))
    if not os.path.exists(var_outdir):
        os.makedirs(var_outdir, 0o777)
    for x in tf.all_variables():
        print(tf.get_variable_scope())
        log("saved variable '{}'.".format(x.name))
        newname = x.name.replace("/",".")
        current_file = os.path.join(var_outdir, newname)
        file = open(current_file, 'w')
        x.eval(session = self.sessions[0]).tofile(file, sep='\t')
        file.close()
```

Restore function:

```
 def restore_from_text(self, variables_dir, meta_file) -> None:
    saver_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{}'.format(meta_file))
    for filename in os.listdir(variables_dir):
        variable_name = filename.replace(".","/")
        variable_files_txt = {}
        file_location = os.path.join(variables_dir, filename)
        variable_file = open(file_location, 'r')
        variable = np.fromfile(variable_file, dtype=float, count=-1, sep='\t')
        #init = tf.constant(variable)
        variable_name = filename.replace(":0","")
        #v = tf.get_variable(variable_name, initializer=init)
        variable_files_txt[variable_name] = variable
    sess = self.sessions[0]   
    for var_name, var in variable_files_txt.items():
         sess.run([var_name+"/Assign"], feed_dict={var_name+"/initial_value:0": var})
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example demonstrating how you can assign a custom value to a variable after creating it.

```
x = tf.Variable(2.)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(x)
```

now you can see the value of this variable is 2, now change its value

```
sess.run("Variable/Assign", feed_dict={"Variable/initial_value:0": 3.})
sess.run(x)
```

now value of this variable is changed to 3.

back to question, first you need to rebuild the graph and also an dictionary which maps variable name to its value like `{"var1": [1, 2], "var2": [2, 3]}`, you can get this dictionary from your saved text file. Then when you have this dictinary, run this command `sess.run(["var1/Assign", "var2/Assign"], feed_dict={"var1/initial_value:0": [1, 2], "var2/initial_value:0": [2, 3]})`

Comment: and how do I restore the graph? Using the import_meta_graph function?

Comment: @MHH yes the easiest way

Comment: Added the full code, do you reckon this should work like a normal saver.restore() call?

Comment: The code has a few minor mistakes, nevermind them, I'm just wondering about the general idea/sequence of it.

Comment: @MHH yes, if you read the source code of saver or just do a visualization of a graph that contains  a saver with tensorboard, you can find that saver.restore(sess, "path/to/variables") is a "control dependence" op of several "variable/Assign" ops which means these "variable/Assign" ops mush run before "control dependence" op run, so they are functionally equivalent

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'trainer/decoder/attention_decoder/cond_gru_2_cell/Gates/Linear/Matrix/Adam_1/initial_value:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'trainer/decoder/attention_decoder/cond_gru_2_cell/Gates/Linear/Matrix/Adam_1/initial_value', does not exist in the graph.

Comment: Any idea why that could be?

Comment: check how your variables were created, the solution I mentioned should work for variables created with `tf.Variable`, but if variables were created with `tf.get_variable`, this solution will not work, you need to find the name of tensor that will be assigned as the value of a variable

Comment: So I'd still use the same command, but I'd have to find the names of the tensors which were used to initialize each variable? Also, after importing the graph, do I need to set it as default graph?

Comment: Yes you need to find the names of tensors; it is set as default graph by default, you don't need to manually do it