# Change weights for TF Checkpoint for training with Slim

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to "manually" manipulate weights for a model checkpoint saved by TF slim. I need to train a new version of an older model with slim for visualization and distributed training. Is there a way to modify randomly intialized weights saved in a checkpoint and train using that checkpoint?

Answer (score 0):

definitly you can, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699824/restore-tensorflow-variable-files-from-plaintext-files/45703828#45703828) for reference

a summary:

you first need a dictionary which map a string to a numpy.array, the string is the name of tensor that will be assign to a variable, and run all the `variable.assign` ops with this dictionary as feed_dict of `sess.run`